# "Promoted to Front Page" option only showing for administrator

Tags: nodes

I am using the "Promoted to Front Page" option for a view that is displayed on a landing page. The option shows in the create/edit form for an administrator, but no other user for the article content type. My "site admin" role allows the user to create/edit own/others for this content type. I am using the group module which is installed for this content type as well as content moderation. This user is assigned to a group with a group role that has permissions for all moderation states. I have looked through all permissions and I don't see a permission to use this. The promoted to front page option is enabled in the manage form display.

Drupal 8.7.7

Comment: Do you use this module, https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options?

Comment: No, we are not using that module. There are no access restrictions placed on those options in our code as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core permission settings require a user to have the "Administer content" permission in order to promote a node to the front page. Evidently the problem has been around since at least Drupal 6 (See [Andy Carter's Blog post](https://andy-carter.com/blog/the-problem-with-drupal-s-administer-nodes-permission-and-how-to-get-round-it)). As suggested in the blog post and in the comment to the question, the [Override Node Options module](https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options) can provide some more refined permissions.